# Feedback form with rating system

Tags: php, mysql, graph, feedback

I want to create a Feedback form for my website with rating system, which will then display the monthly average rating to a separate page as a graph.

I do have a little concept. But It's lacking something. I know how to create a feedback form. But I am confused on how to save it in Mysql. I mean do I need to calculate the average rating before saving it to mysql or when calling from the graphs page.

Please help me with concept or example.

Thanks.

Comment: C'mon, you can easily Google this. I doubt Google has an **"embargo"** for your country.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not Google please. Read the rules of making question!

Comment: Dude.. I do have a little concept. But It's lacking something. I know how to create a feedback form. But I am confused on how to save it in Mysql. I mean do I need to calculate the average rating before saving it to mysql or when calling from the graphs page. @Fred

Comment: @PeeJay Then show us what you already have. And don't call me **"dude"**, it's **"Fred"**.

Comment: @Fred.. sorry for that. I would love to show you my work if it was returning any error. It was just lacking a solid concept which has been clarified by 2chris9696

Comment: @PeeJay Thank you. Now, I did NOT downvote your question, but from what you can see, there is already 2 downvotes. I suggest that you first get a fair grasp on MySQL/MySQLi if you haven't already done so, before getting into such a project. There are many different types of rating systems out there, some of them who do not require a backend in DB. I've worked with many types in the past, some of which were CGI-based, some PHP with jQuery/Ajax while using a flatfile .txt. Some will criticize .txt based, but using the right way to protect those files, is rather easy through the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks @Fred. I will take a note of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a form, where the user will put all the rating and the info.

When the user press the "Send" button you will execute a PHP code, this script will take the value of the form, and insert them inside a database, with the current year / month.

When you will go on the page that will show the rating you will execute a php code that will take all the rating in the current year/month from the database , sum them, and do the average calculation. Then you will show the value.

Comment: Thanks man. I will try working it out using your concept.